# SQL: Add A Foreign Key relation to two existing(filled) tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables: One table is the `albums` table that contains the album name, author and genre(s) (As well as an insertion timestamp). The other is the `tracks` table, which contains information about each of the tracks on an album (As well as an insertion timestamp).

Today I realized that a lot of data in my tables is double: In the `tracks` table, I also store the album and author name, while it would be nicer to select them from the other table by referencing them only with an ID.

I know I can uniquely identify the album each track belongs to because it has:

- The same album name
- A timestamp which is not more than a few seconds apart.

Is there a way for me to create a column that references the album_id from SQL alone, or do I need to write a program in e.g. PHP to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in SQL.

- Add album id to tracks table (would have to be nullable to begin with)
- Add foreign key
- Update tracks table based on some common property such as album name
- Make foreign key not nullable, optional step

e.g.

```
update tracks set album_id = a.id
from albums a
where tracks.album_name = a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already added the album_ID column I'd suggest the following commands:

To add album_ID:

```
ALTER TABLE albums ADD album_ID VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE tracks ADD album_ID VARCHAR(10);
```

To add the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE tracks ADD FOREIGN KEY (album_ID) REFERENCES albums(album_ID);
```

To drop album name and author name:

```
ALTER TABLE tracks DROP COLUMN album_name;
ALTER TABLE tracks DROP COLUMN author_name;
```

Then populate the album ID's in both tables.

Comment: You are missing many steps in your answer which might give him headaches.